# Can you colonize a planet that has 100% blocked tiles?

Tags: stellaris

There is a colonizable planet I found which looks interesting, but **all** tiles on the surface are either yellow or red from various blocker effects. Normally I'd be able to clean them out after landing on it, but I can't send a colony ship now because you need to land the colony ship on an open tile.

Is there any way I can still colonize this planet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you [terraform](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Terraforming) the planet, it will remove all the blockers, allowing you to colonize it.

Comment: It's a short and sweet answer but I was gunna write the same thing.

Comment: @n_palum I was about to add a link to a wiki, but you beat me, so we're even.